# php config - generate hashed password manually

Tags: php, php-fpm, password-management

I've created a php conf file, which include some user / password infos. For testing purposes I've added the password for the database in plain text. Since this can't be a good idea, I want to change that plain password into a hashed password.

Is that possible and if so, how can I achieve that?

Do I have to update the MariaDB database as well when changing the php conf and using a hashed password?

Comment: What do you mean by "php conf"? Can you show an example of that?

Comment: I think you haven't understood what `hashed password` means.